# VisualStudio CodeLens: how to show references to mebers like for properties and methods

Tags: visual-studio, codelens

In VisualStudio (2015): is it possible to show references to a member variable like for properties and methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the field definition you can "Find all references" (Shift-F12 by default).

[I have no idea why Code Lens isn't applied to fields, so need to use pre-Code Lens functionality.]